# Multiple Where Conditions In .Net Core API Linq Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, search

The API that I've been writing includes a search that's supposed to check the database and see if the video IDs included in searchVideoIDs[] are mapped to the corresponding tags from searchTagID[]. For example, Video 1 and Video 2 both have entries in the database where the tagID is set to 3.

This request is able to fetch the individual entry for both video IDs that's linked to tag 3, meaning that `http://localhost:5000/api/MapVideoTag/findVideo/?searchTagID=3&searchVideoIDs=1` works but...

When both IDs are passed in one API call, such as `http://localhost:5000/api/MapVideoTag/findVideo/?searchTagID=3&searchVideoIDs=1&searchVideoIDs=2` the result I get is an empty array.

I'd appreciate any insight as to why my request isn't returning all the values - here's my code below.

```
[HttpGet("findVideo/{searchTagID?}/{searchVideoIDs?}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MapVideoTag>> FindVideoTags([FromQuery]string[] searchVideoIDs, [FromQuery]string[] searchTagID)
{
     //this item will be used to access the mapped tags
     var mappedTagItem = from mappedtag in _context.MapVideoTag select mappedtag;
     foreach (string videoID in searchVideoIDs) {
        bool verifyVideo = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(videoID);
        foreach (string tagID in searchTagID) {
           bool verifyTag = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tagID);
           if (verifyTag == true && verifyVideo == true) {
               var parsedVideo = int.Parse(videoID);
               var parsedTag = int.Parse(tagID);
               mappedTagItem = mappedTagItem.Where(v =>
               (v.VideoId == parsedVideo)
                &&
                (v.TagId == parsedTag)
                );
                }
                }
            return mappedTagItem.ToList();
              }
```

Comment: you sure your parameter `searchVideoIDs` has a value?

Comment: @Veljko89 mhm! i'm certain, i tested these calls out in postman and after passing in these values i'm able to get results when searching to see if an individual video has a tag. the big issue that i have is when i'm seeing if multiple videos include a tag, i only get a 200 OK status code with an empty array instead of the two entries that i'd like.